# Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s) not found

Tags: wordpress

When I upload mp4 video to the media it show me this error " **Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s) not found**  "

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pJUA.png)